# Using multiple viewModels within knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I'd like to keep my knockout script more organized, moreover, I'd like to avoid naming 2 functions the same thing by accident.  So I was wondering if I could nest viewModels in the same function like so (I kept it real simple): [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/likwid_t/KnBrE/)

Here's the HTML

```
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: other.firstName">todo</strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: other.lastName">todo</strong></p>
<p>Full name: <strong data-bind="text: other.fullName">todo</strong></p>
```

and the JS:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.other = {
        firstName: ko.observable("Bert"),
        lastName: ko.observable("Bertington"),
        /*fullName: ko.computed(function(){
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
            }, this)*/

        }
}
```

This works fine, but if I uncomment the ko.computed it'll crash.  Is there any way to organize my knockout in this way, why is the computed crashing, is there any way to write the ko.computed function so it will work?

**EDIT: Problem #2**

If I have a form any form like this:

```
<form data-bind="submit: other.otherSubmit" data-ajax="false">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and I add a handler for submit like so:

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.other = new function(){     
            var self = this;
            self.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
            self.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
            self.fullName = ko.computed(function(){            
                return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
                });
            self.otherSumbit = function(){}
            }
    }

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

why does the error console return this:

*The value for a submit binding must be a function*

Comment: Thank you both it turns out what was missing in the program that I was writing was that I had written self.other = function(){... and not self.other = new function(){... the "new" basically made my entire program work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can try this:

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
    function AppViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.other = new function(){     
            var self = this;
            self.firstName = ko.observable("Bert");
            self.lastName = ko.observable("Bertington");
            self.fullName = ko.computed(function(){            
                return self.firstName() + " " + self.lastName();
                });        
            }
    }

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your first case was that in that context, `this` referred to the view model.  Within your object literal, your object did not exist yet so you wouldn't have been able to set up your computed observable that way.  You would've had to add it to the object after it was created.

Either like this (which is ugly):

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.other = {
        firstName: ko.observable('Bert'),
        lastName:  ko.observable('Bertington')
    };
    self.other.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
    }, self.other);
}
```

Or like this (as you've done similarly in your second example):

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.other = new function() {
        this.firstName = ko.observable('Bert');
        this.lastName = ko.observable('Bertington');
        this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
            return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName();
        }, this);
    };
}
```

Of course there are other ways you could write the above examples but you get my point.

---

In your second example, you just misspelled your function.  In the view model it was named `otherSumbit` while your view had it `otherSubmit`.

Comment: Thanks, let me try some stuff out I'll no doubt accept in a few minutes

Answer (score 0):

one technique that I use to organize my VM using knockout:

```
//load view
    $.get(url, function(view){
        $("#content').html(view);
        ko.applyBindings(new myVM(), $('#content')[0]);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone looking for a solution for this kind of solution please try following method

Html View

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container1">
        <ul>
            <li >Container1 item</li>
            <!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
            <li>Item <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="container2">
        <ul>
            <li >Container2 item</li>
            <!-- ko foreach: myItems -->
                <li>Item <span data-bind="text: $data"></span></li>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/knockout-3.0.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/DataFunction.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Container1ViewModel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Container2ViewModel.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

For this view I'm creating 2 view models for id=container1 and id=container2 in two separate javascript files.

Container1ViewModel.js

```
function Container1ViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.myItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.myItems.push("ABC");
    self.myItems.push("CDE");

}
```

Container2ViewModel.js

```
function Container2ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.myItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.myItems.push("XYZ");
    self.myItems.push("PQR");

}
```

Then after these 2 viewmodels are registering as separate viewmodels in DataFunction.js

```
var container1VM;
var container2VM;

$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($.isEmptyObject(container1VM)) {
        container1VM = new Container1ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(container1VM, document.getElementById("container1"));
    }

    if ($.isEmptyObject(container2VM)) {
        container2VM = new Container2ViewModel();
        ko.applyBindings(container2VM, document.getElementById("container2"));
    }
});
```

Like this you can add any number of viewmodels for separate divs. But make sure do not create separate view model for a div inside registered div.